# Max(created_at) showing the right column but not the rest of the data SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch the latest entry to the database

I have this data

[image]

When I run this query

`select id, parent_id, amount, max(created_at) from table group by parent_id`
it correctly returns the latest entry but not the rest of the column

[image]

what I want is

[image]

how do I achieve that?

Sorry that I posted image instead of table, the table won't work for some reason

Comment: This data is not enough. Please share proper data and result expected from that data. Also, share scripts.

Comment: @AmitVerma what other data you need?

Comment: @AmitVerma if this helps what I want to achieve is something like this from the laravel documentation $latestPosts = DB::table('posts')
                   ->select('user_id', DB::raw('MAX(created_at) as last_post_created_at'))
                   ->where('is_published', true)
                   ->groupBy('user_id');
 
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->joinSub($latestPosts, 'latest_posts', function ($join) {
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'latest_posts.user_id');
        })->get();

Comment: As to the images: You can just copy the data from your database tool and paste them into your request. The simplest way then to format them is with the code button (`{}`). Or use a table formatting tool like https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ (where yoe set the desired format to Github Markdown).

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the desired output using subquery. In the subquery fetch the max created_at of each parent_id which will return the row with max created_at for each parent_id. Please try the below query.

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable t WHERE t.created_at = 
(SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM yourtable WHERE parent_id = t.parent_id);
```

If the id column in your table is AUTO_INCREMENT field then you can fetch the latest entry with the help of id column too.

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable t WHERE t.id = 
(SELECT MAX(id) FROM yourtable WHERE parent_id = t.parent_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a good use case for a window function like `RANK` as a subquery:

```
SELECT id, parent_id, amount, created_at 
FROM ( 
  SELECT id, parent_id, amount, created_at, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) parentID_rank
    FROM yourtable) groupedData
WHERE parentID_rank = 1;
```

or with `ORDER BY` clause for the outer query if necessary:

```
SELECT id, parent_id, amount, created_at 
FROM ( 
  SELECT id, parent_id, amount, created_at, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) parentID_rank
    FROM yourtable) groupedData
WHERE parentID_rank = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

To explain the intention:

The `PARTITION BY` clause groups your data by the parent_id.

The `ORDER BY` clause sorts it starting with the latest date.

The `WHERE` clause just takes the entry with the latest date per parent id only.

Answer (score 1):

The main point here is that your query is invalid. The DBMS should raise an error, but you work in a cheat mode that MySQL offers that allows you to write such queries without being warned.

My advice: When working in MySQL make sure you have always

```
SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
```

As to the query: You are using `MAX`. Thus you aggregate your data. In your `GROUP BY` clause you say you want one result row per parent_id. You select the parent_id's maximum created_at. You also select the parent_id's ID, the parent_id itself, and the parent_id's amount. *The* parent_id's ID??? Is there only one ID per parent_id in your table? *The* amount? Is there only one amount per parent_id in the table? You must tell the DBMS which ID to show and which amount. You haven't done so, and this makes your query invalid according to standard SQL.

You are running MySQL in cheat mode,however, and so MySQL silently applies ANY_VALUE to all non-aggregated columns. This is what your query is turned into internally:

```
select
  any_value(id),
  parent_id,
  any_value(amount),
  max(created_at)
from table
group by parent_id;
```

`ANY_VALUE` means the DBMS is free to pick the attribute from whatever row it likes; you don't care.

What you want instead is not to aggregate your rows, but to filter them. You want to select only those rows with the maximum created_at per parent_id.

There exist several ways to get this result. Here are some options.

**Get the maximum created_at per parent_id. Then select the matching rows:**

```
select *
from table 
where (parent_id, created_at) in
(
  select parent_id, max(created_at)
  from table
  group by parent_id
);
```

**Select the rows for which no newer created_at exists for the parent_id:**

```
select *
from table t
where not exists
(
  select null
  from table newer
  where newer.parent_id = t.parent_id
  and newer.created_at > t.created_at
);
```

**Get the maximum created_at on-the-fly. Then compare the dates:**

```
select id, parent_id, amount, created_at
from
(
  select t.*, max(created_at) over (partition by parent_id) as max_created_at
  from table t
) with_max_created_at
where created_at = max_created_at;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select id, parent_id, amount, max(created_at)
from table
group by parent_id 
order by max(created_at) desc 
limit 1
```

Comment: it won't work. it still return the first row

Comment: @npe: You seem to have both misunderstood the request and not seen the real problem with the original query. The OP says that their query returns undesired values in the result rows. (The reason for this is that their query is invalid and they work in a mode that tells MySQL to run the query nontheless.) Your solution does not correct wrong values in the columns, but merely limits the wrong rows to one single wrong row. (And your query is still invalid.) And please never post code-only answers. Explain how your query works and in what way it solves the problem.